# Connecting Kafka connect source directly to the kafka connect sink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I want to sync two tables from two distinct database services with `Kafka Connect Source` and `Kafka Connect Sink`.

`Kafka Connect Source` reads data from source database and publishes changes into a topic named TOP1, and `Kafka Connect Sink` subscribed into the TOP1 and should write the change into the destination database.

The source and destination database are `MSSQL` and I use `Debezium connector for SQL Server`.

I created Kafka Connect Source with following configuration:

```
{
  "name": "sql-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "database.server.name": "TEST",
    "database.dbname": "test_source",
    "database.hostname": "172.1x.xx.xx",
    "database.port": "1433",
    "database.user": "sa",
    "database.password": "xxxxx",
    "database.instance": "MSSQLSERVER",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka01.xxxx.dev:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://kafka01.xxxx.dev:8081"
  }
}
```

This works great and publish any changes(insert, update, delete) with following schema:

```
{
"before": {...},
"after": {...},
"source": {...}
}
```

But how should I create `Kafka Connect Sink` configuration that in destination database I have exactly the same data as source database.
When a record inserted in source the same insert in destination, a record deleted in source the same record delete from destination and also update in source results update in the destination.

Comment: You cannot connect the two directly. That's defeats the point of Kafka. What sink are you trying to use?

Comment: I use `io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector`. what solution should I use for this purpose?

Comment: That should work fine. What specific issues are you having with it?

Comment: For example When I delete a record from the source database `sink` service dosen't delete that row in the destination, it inserts a new record with filled `before` and empty `after` as i said in question.

Comment: Sounds like you are not familiar with the unwrap transformation. See full example here syncing different databases https://medium.com/swlh/sync-mysql-to-postgresql-using-debezium-and-kafkaconnect-d6612489fd64